# Can't send file to server using THTTPClient

Tags: php, delphi, file-upload, delphi-11-alexandria

**Embarcadero® Delphi 11.0 Version 28.0.**

**task**: send file `d:\1.txt` to server http://example.com/upload.php to save in http://example.com home dir

server logs

```
[19/Jan/2024:21:08:46 +0500] "POST /upload.php HTTP/1.0" 200 3507 "-" "Embarcadero URI Client/1.0"
```

Delphi app code:

```pascal
var
  HTTPClient: THTTPClient;
begin
  HTTPClient := THTTPClient.Create;
  try
    
    // Установка Content-Type заголовка
    HTTPClient.CustomHeaders['Content-Type'] := 'application/octet-stream';
    
    // Загрузка файла на сервер
    HTTPClient.Post('http://example.com/upload.php', TFileStream.Create('d:\1.txt', fmOpenRead), nil);
  finally
    HTTPClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

PHP server code:

```php
<?php
// Путь для сохранения загруженного файла
$targetPath = '/path/to/save/1.txt';
 
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    // Перемещение загруженного файла в заданное место
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath)) {
        // Файл успешно загружен
        echo 'Success: File uploaded successfully.';
    } else {
        // Ошибка перемещения файла
        echo 'Error: Unable to move uploaded file.';
    }
} else {
    // Ошибка загрузки файла
    echo 'Error: File upload error.';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

`$_FILES` requires you to upload the file wrapped in the `multipart/form-data` media type, but you are just sending the raw file as-is instead.

You need to give `THTTPClient.Post()` a `TMultipartFormData` instead of a `TFileStream` (which BTW, you are leaking), eg:

```
uses
  ..., System.Net.HttpClient, System.Net.Mime, System.Net.URLClient;

var
  HTTPClient: THTTPClient;
  PostData: TMultipartFormData;
begin
  HTTPClient := THTTPClient.Create;
  try
    PostData := TMultipartFormData.Create;
    try
      PostData.AddFile('file', 'd:\1.txt', 'text/plain');
      HTTPClient.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data';
      HTTPClient.Post('http://example.com/upload.php', PostData, nil);
    finally
      PostData.Free;
    end;
  finally
    HTTPClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: add uses   REST.Client;
but TMultipartFormData stay e2003 Undeclared. Why?

Comment: Embarcadero® Delphi 11.0 Version 28